# Adding Table to Existed Word Document using DocX

Tags: c#, novacode-docx

I need to add table with some data to an existed Word template and I'm using novacode-docx Lib. 
However, there is an issue that I can't locate. For some templates, everything works fine but for others I'm getting an error. So here is my code

```
//copying template file
File.Copy(Info.reportTemplatePath+reportTemplateName+".docx",(path + fileName));
var doc = DocX.Load(path + fileName);
Table tb = doc.AddTable(3,3);
//Table tb = doc.InsertTable(0, 3,3); 
Font font = new Font(new FontFamily("Times New Roman"), 12f,FontStyle.Bold);
tb.Alignment = Alignment.both;
tb.Paragraphs[0].Font(new FontFamily("Times New Roman"));

tb.Design = TableDesign.TableNormal;
tb.SetBorder(TableBorderType.Bottom, new Border(BorderStyle.Tcbs_none, 0,1,Color.Transparent));
tb.Rows[0].Cells[0].Paragraphs[0].Append("Patient Name: "+mirrorText(patientName) ).Alignment=Alignment.left; 
tb.Rows[0].Cells[1].Paragraphs[0].Append("DOB: " +DOB  );
tb.Rows[0].Cells[2].Paragraphs[0].Append("Visit Date: "+visitDate  ).Alignment = Alignment.right;
tb.Rows[1].Cells[0].Paragraphs[0].Append("Patient ID: " + patientID).Alignment=Alignment.left;
tb.Rows[1].Cells[2].Paragraphs[0].Append(" ");
tb.Rows[2].Cells[2].Paragraphs[0].Append("المحترم "+mirrorText(referredDoctor) + " الدكتور " + " :المرسل " + "الطبيب").Alignment = Alignment.right;
tb.Rows[0].Cells[0].Width = 330d;
tb.Rows[0].Cells[1].Width = 190d;
tb.Rows[0].Cells[2].Width = 220d;
tb.Rows[0].Cells[2].Paragraphs[0].FontSize(12);
tb.Rows[0].Cells[1].Paragraphs[0].FontSize(12);
tb.Rows[0].Cells[0].Paragraphs[0].FontSize(12);
tb.Rows[1].Cells[0].Paragraphs[0].FontSize(12);
tb.Rows[2].Cells[2].Paragraphs[0].FontSize(14);
tb.Rows[0].Cells[2].Paragraphs[0].Bold();
tb.Rows[0].Cells[1].Paragraphs[0].Bold();
tb.Rows[0].Cells[0].Paragraphs[0].Bold();
tb.Rows[1].Cells[0].Paragraphs[0].Bold();
tb.Rows[2].Cells[2].Paragraphs[0].Bold();
tb.Rows[0].Cells[2].Paragraphs[0].Font(new FontFamily("Times New Roman"));
tb.Rows[0].Cells[1].Paragraphs[0].Font(new FontFamily("Times New Roman"));
tb.Rows[0].Cells[0].Paragraphs[0].Font(new FontFamily("Times New Roman"));
tb.Rows[1].Cells[0].Paragraphs[0].Font(new FontFamily("Times New Roman"));
tb.Rows[2].Cells[2].Paragraphs[0].Font(new FontFamily("Times New Roman"));
tb.Rows[2].MergeCells(0, 2);
tb.Rows[2].Cells[0].RemoveParagraphAt(0);
tb.Rows[2].Cells[0].RemoveParagraphAt(0);

doc.InsertTable(0,tb); // I am getting the error here which is {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
//   doc.InsertParagraph("المحترم " + mirrorText(referredDoctor) + " الدكتور " + " :المرسل " + "الطبيب", false, patientFormat).Alignment = Alignment.right;
doc.InsertParagraph(string.Empty, false);
doc.AddFooters();
doc.MarginBottom = 0.1f;
Footer footer = doc.Footers.odd;
Bitmap tempFoImg = Info.generateFooterImage();
//  System.Drawing.Image tempImg=(System.Drawing.Image)tempFoImg;

MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();
tempFoImg.Save(ms2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
ms2.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
Novacode.Image img2 = doc.AddImage(ms2);
Picture footerImage = img2.CreatePicture();
Paragraph p4 = footer.InsertParagraph("", false).InsertPicture(footerImage, 0);
p4.Alignment = Novacode.Alignment.center;
doc.Save();
Process.Start(path + fileName);
```

The error is located here :   `doc.InsertTable(0,tb); //  {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}`
I am using  0 to append the table at the top of the document, and when I remove the location, it works fine some times 
I am willing to use different lib. if it solves the problem, and thank you in advance

Comment: so what is the error that you are getting.. it would surely help to explain / post the error.. also tons of memory issues / non disposal issues in your current code..

Comment: I will be happy if you give me hints about how to solve these tons of memory issues

Comment: when you create instances of objects you must free them.. do a google search on how to dispose of objects, are you familiar with the `using( ) { }` construct..? if not google that for examples as well

Comment: Sure I will, thank you

Comment: you still have not stated what the error is you are getting btw also why are you wrapping your 2nd parameter around `(` in this line 
`File.Copy(Info.reportTemplatePath+reportTemplateName+".docx",(path + fileName));` use the string.Format function to pass {0} +{1}, {2}+{3}, "your four values or variables")

Comment: I updated the Q. But The error is located here :  doc.InsertTable(0,tb); //  {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: have you used the debugger and stepped thru the code.. what is the of value of `tb` after this line..?
`Table tb = doc.AddTable(3,3);`

Comment: I guess I look for another lib. because I am getting several issues with this one like text mirroring. Thank you anyway